# Temp Table like thing in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a scenario where I need to use tabular data which is unlikely to change but which helps implement business logic:

```
Table

 Parent      Child         Relationship      Allowed
  A            B                 C            True
  B            A                 C            False
```

Each row represent a business rule. Based on this table I need to populate a dropdown control with the contents of the "Relationship" column. Can I have some sort of data structure within C# to store this tabular data, or do I need to use a a database table?

Comment: Why not make a class that models your data?

Comment: Does this data need to be accessed across several different pages or do you just need it for the one page with the drop down?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you need to persist this data across sessions, you don't need to store it in a database table. From the perspective of Object Oriented design, why not make an object, and therefore class, that represents the structure you need. Something like this:

```
public class Relationship
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Child { get; set; }
    public bool Allowed { get; set; }
}
```

Note of course that I'm using strings where you might want to use further objects of their own 'type'. Additionally, keep in mind access, and what should and shouldn't be allowed to access these properties... This is example is intentionally simple at this point!

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that a full blown database *may* be overkill if this is all the data you need to store, so you *could* theoretically hardcode the data and structure in C# if you really wanted to, but not a good idea in almost all cases - even if it is unlikely to change.

At a minimum store the data in a little XML / config file so that IF it does change, you do not need to recompile the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTable.aspx

You can create your Table and fill it like this:

```
// Definition
DataTable table = new DataTable();

DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Parent", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add(column);

// Data
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["Parent"] = "A";
table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: I think a table is overkill unless the 'object' needs to be put in a database, or is tied logically to another item that is already a table.

Comment: Overkill in what way? Memory-wise?

Comment: Just from a simplicity perspective really! If you can represent what you need with a POCO, you may as well do so.